# How to write an awk program that creates subfolders and populates each with a file?

Tags: awk

My input file (`test.txt`) consists of records, each record contains person-name tab number:

```
John    1
Mary    2
```

I have a folder named `test` and I want my awk program to create a subfolder for each record, using the person-name as the subfolder name and populate each subfolder with a file `person.txt` using the record as its content. That is, my awk program should create this folder structure:

```
test
    John
        person.txt  # contains John tab 1
    Mary
        person.txt  # contains Mary tab 2
```

Below is my awk program. When I run it, I get this error message:

```
awk: test.awk:7: fatal: cannot redirect to 'test/John/person.txt': No such file or directory
```

This is line 7:

```
print $0 >destination; fflush()
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Here is my awk program (`test.awk`):

```
BEGIN   {
          FS = OFS = "\t"
          while (getline <"test.txt" > 0) {
            foldername="test/" $1
            system("if [ ! -d foldername ]; then mkdir foldername; fi")
            destination = foldername "/person.txt"
            print $0 >destination; fflush()
          }
        }
```

Comment: Awk seems like a poor choice for this task. You will end up calling `system` anyway, i.e. effectively a shell script.

Comment: Anyway, `mkdir -p` will succeed silently if the directory already exists.

Comment: `foldername` does not expand in double quotes, so `system("if [ ! -d foldername ]...` is using the literal name `foldername`.

Comment: @William Pursell How to get foldername to expand?

Comment: `while IFS=$'\t' read -r name number; do mkdir -p test/"$name"; printf '%s\t\s\n' "$name" "$number" >test/"$name"/person.txt <test.txt` (the "C-style string" `$'\t'` is a Bash feature, but you can replace it with a literal tab in single quotes, without the `$` prefix).

Comment: @RogerCostello Either take it out of quotes (eg `sytem("if [ ! -d " foldername " ...`) or use `sprintf` to construct the command.  But...this is entirely the wrong approach.

Comment: Thank you @William Pursell Learning that my awk-oriented approach is not the right approach, and then learning the right shell-based approach, is very valuable to me (and to others I suspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, if the "heavy lifting" of your awk is done using "system", it indicate that you are using the wrong tool for the job. Either pure-shell, or pure-bash will do better. Personally, I will go for shell:

```
while read name values ; do
    dirname="test/$name"
    # Create dirname of not already exists
    [ -d "$dirname" ] || mkdir "$dirname"
    # Create content file (person.txt)
    echo -e "$name\t$values" > $dirname/person.txt
done < test.txt
```